# dynamic_cast causing a bad_cast error

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

I am trying to understand how dynamic_cast works. I have a class interfaceElement with a class menu derived from it. In my program, I create no objects of class interfaceElement. When executing the following code (executing the line with dynamic_cast, to be more precise), the bad_cast exception is thrown

```
void drawInterfaceElement(interfaceElement elem, int colour1, int colour2)
{
    if (elem.getType()=="MENU")
    {
        menu &cur = dynamic_cast<menu&>(elem);
        this->drawMenu(&cur,colour1,colour2);
    }
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `interfaceElement` by reference. Currently you incur slicing by taking by value, causing the `menu` subobject to be lost. `dynamic_cast` cannot cast to that type, causing `std::bad_cast` to be thrown (if you were converting to a pointer, a null pointer would be returned).

See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: I have taken interfaceElement by reference, it didn't help. The same error is still thrown.

Comment: @Vladgor Your vector should hold `interfaceElement*` or `shared_ptr<interfaceElement>`. You have slicing going on there too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing `elem` by value. So it is an `interfaceElement` object and cannot be case to a derived type.

You need to pass by reference:

```
void drawInterfaceElement(interfaceElement& elem, int colour1, int colour2)
                                          ^
```

Comment: I have done it, didn't help.

Comment: @Vladgor Then the object you're passing isn't a `menu`.

Comment: vector <interfaceElement> Interface;
    menu *Menu = new menu(&System);
    Interface.push_back(*Menu);
    artist.drawInterfaceElement(Interface[0],7,15);

Comment: @Vladgor You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).